# javascript and live connect

Tags: java, javascript, liveconnect

i wrote a simple html file that prints 10 random numbers using javascript. javascript object in turn uses java.util.Random class (live connect) to output the result! but i am not getting exact output when using with functions and events like onLoad or onclick!

> ```
> <html>
> <body onLoad="hello()">
> <script language="javascript">
> function hello()
> {
> var i=0;
> for(;i<10;i++)
> {
> var j=new java.util.Random(i);
> document.writeln(j);
> }
> }
> </script></body></html>
> ```

And i can get output if we dont use function!

> ```
> <html>
> <body >
> <script language="javascript">
> var i=0;
> for(;i<10;i++)
> {
> var j=new java.util.Random(i);
> document.writeln(j);
> }
> </script></body></html>
> ```

can anybody help me with this bug!

Comment: It's apparently a replacement for Math.random()

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

`var j=Math.random()*i;` instead of `var j=new java.util.Random(i);`

Comment: but my doubt is, the code is working perfectly when we directly write it inside script tag and the code is not working when we put it in a function??!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the correct syntax?

```
for(;i<10;i++){
  Random r =  new Random();
  int j =  r.nextInt(i)
  document.writeln(j);
}
```